# Installing another Android SDK version

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I'm getting the following:

```
C:\Users\ewgof\source\TargetSum> npx react-native doctor
Common
 ✓ Node.js
 ✓ yarn

Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 33.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

Errors:   1
Warnings: 0

Usage
 › Press f to try to fix issues.
 › Press e to try to fix errors.
 › Press w to try to fix warnings.
 › Press Enter to exit.
```

Android Studio says that I have Android SDK Build-Tools 34:

[image]

Therefore, I'm trying to install the Android SDK version 33 like so:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\5.0\bin> .\sdkmanager.bat --install "cmdline-tools;33.0.0"
Warning: Failed to find package 'cmdline-tools;33.0.0'
```

Any suggestions for getting version 33 of the SDK to install?

I've tried checking the Show Package Details on the SDK Platforms but I'm not seeing Android SDK Build there:

[image]

I was able to get to a view similar to what you are showing by clicking on the SDK Tools tab instead of SDK Platforms:

[image: SDK Tools]

Strangely, it appears that I already have version 33 installed.

Comment: the SDK build tool will be under "SDK tools" not "SDK Platforms". Click on the "SDK Tools" tab and make sure to check "Show Package Details" and you will see the option for 33 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on SDK Platforms
[image]

Check the "Show Package Details"

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried following your suggestions, but I don't see the Android SDK Build Tools there (I've added a screenshot to my post).

Comment: the SDK build tool will be under "SDK tools" not "SDK Platforms".
Click on the "SDK Tools" tab and make sure to check "Show Package Details" and you will see the option for 33 as well.

Comment: I was able to get `npx react-native doctor` to pass by installing the `Andoid SDK Command-line Tools (latest)` on the `SDK Tools` tab.